# Playing sound on local computer after command in SSH connection

Tags: ssh, audio, linux-mint, ubuntu-9.10

I'm in a `ssh` connection and I would like to play a sound after a command completes (not on the server where I connected).

Something:

```
ssh me@somewhere.com
make && play-sound-local
```

I have built-in pc-speaker disabled so `echo -e "\a"` doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Very similar question, with answer: "[Playing a sound/notification in finch over ssh on my local machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34777)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure PulseAudio to allow network connections, then use ssh port forwarding and `paplay -s` on the remote side to send audio back through the ssh connection. Note that the audio may be delayed or stutter based on the fidelity of the audio and the speed of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Set up primitive server (for example, on port 1234) that plays sound on local computer when someone connects, and forward that port to remote server.

On local machine:

```
nc -l -p 1234 -e "mplayer sound.ogg"
```

then

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:12345 me@somewhere.com
make && nc localhost 12345
```

PS: you should use `;` instead of `&&` if you want to be notified even when make failed.

Answer (score 1):

**(This is the [answer by @xzfc](https://superuser.com/a/784319) with some corrections.)**

1. Install `ncat` on your client and server machine. Because `nc` in usual distributions (Debian, Ubuntu) does not have the options to execute commands (`-c` / `-e`) which we need.

   ```
   apt install nmap
   ```
2. On your local machine, set up a server that will [execute a command to play a sound](https://askubuntu.com/q/277215) when a connection is established to it:

   ```
   ncat --sh-exec "paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga" \
     --keep-open --listen localhost 10009
   ```

   Or use the equivalent shorthand command:

   ```
   ncat -klc "paplay file.oga" localhost 10009
   ```
3. SSH into your remote host in such a way that a reverse tunnel is established from port 10008 of the remote host to port 10009 on your local machine (where your server is listening):

   ```
   ssh -R 10008:localhost:10009 me@somewhere.com
   ```
4. Execute your `make` command as follows in the SSH shell:

   ```
   make; ncat --idle-timeout 1s localhost 10008
   ```

**How it works**

After the `make` command (whether successful or not), the `ncat` command establishes a connection to port 10008 on the remote host, which SSH forwards to port 10009 on your local machine, where your server listens and will play a sound when the connection is made. After the connection has been established, we no longer need it, so it is closed after `--idle-timeout 1s`. This will show the shell prompt again instead of a "hanging" `ncat` command, making it apparent that your SSH command chain really finished.

The SSH reverse tunneling makes this work in spite of any routers / firewalls / NAT between your local machine and the remote machine. (Otherwise you would have to set up port forwarding rules in your router, or have a local machine exposed to the Internet.)

**Security**

We do `ncat -l localhost 10009` for the server, which means it listens only on the network interface with the localhost IP address. This local loop interface only allows connections from your own machine (including, in this case, those reverse tunneled in via SSH). So even if you are not behind a firewall, your port 10009 is not exposed to anyone on the Internet.